# How to unroll a dataframe which has a tree structure inside it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, tree

I have a data frame, which has a sort of tree structure, like this:

df1

```
     Class   Type    Sub-class
 0    1        ~       D
 1    1        ~       C
 2    1        ~       B
 3    1        ~       A
 4    1        ~       14
 5    1        P       NaN       
 6    A        ~       C
 7    A        ~       D
 8    A        ~       7
 9    A        ~       B
10    A        P       NaN
11    B        ~       D
12    B        ~       4
13    B        ~       C
14    B        P       NaN
15    C        ~       D
16    C        ~       4
17    C        P       NaN
18    D        ~       18
19    D        ~       9
20    D        P       NaN
```

Class D is only made out of numerical classes. Is defined as:

```
D        ~       18
D        ~       9
D        P       NaN
```

Class C is made out of 1 numerical class, and class D. Is defined as:

```
C        ~       D
C        ~       4
C        P       NaN
```

Class B is made out of 1 numerical class, class D, and class C. Is defined as:

```
B        ~       D
B        ~       4
B        ~       C
B        P       NaN
```

Class A is made out of 1 numerical class, class D, class C, and class B. Is defined as:

```
A        ~       C
A        ~       D
A        ~       7
A        ~       B
A        P       NaN
```

Class 1 is made out of 1 numerical class, class D, class C, class B and Class A. Is defined as:

```
1        ~       D
1        ~       C
1        ~       B
1        ~       A
1        ~       14
1        P       NaN
```

The aim is to get a final data frame which has is a total concatenation of all the Classes - for example, when Class D is mentioned in the `Sub-class` column in df1, I need to replace that entire row with Class D which is

```
Class   Type    Sub-class
D        ~       18
D        ~       9
D        P       NaN
```

This is how the final dataframe should look (I have replaced row 15 in `df1`, with Class D for example). The aim is to make the `Sub-class` column to only consist of numerical classes:

df_final

```
     Class   Type    Sub-class
 0    1        ~       D      <--- Replace this Row with Class D
 1    1        ~       C      <--- Replace this Row with Class C
 2    1        ~       B      <--- Replace this Row with Class B
 3    1        ~       A      <--- Replace this Row with Class A
 4    1        ~       14
 5    1        P       NaN       
 6    A        ~       C      <--- Replace this Row with Class C
 7    A        ~       D      <--- Replace this Row with Class D
 8    A        ~       7
 9    A        ~       B      <--- Replace this Row with Class B
10    A        P       NaN
11    B        ~       D      <--- Replace this Row with Class D
12    B        ~       4
13    B        ~       C      <--- Replace this Row with Class C
14    B        P       NaN
15    D        ~       18
16    D        ~       9
17    D        P       NaN
18    C        ~       4
19    C        P       NaN
20    D        ~       18
21    D        ~       9
22    D        P       NaN
```

Comment: Your df1 and df_final haven't the same len(), I answered you based on your df1.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is what you're looking for:

```
df['Class'] = (np.where(
              (df['Sub-class'] == 'A') | (df['Sub-class'] == 'B') | (df['Sub-class'] == 'C') | (df['Sub-class'] == 'D'), #conditions
               df['Sub-class'], #values if True
               df['Class'])) #values if False
```

Result:

| index | Class | Type | Sub-class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | D | ~ | D |
| 1 | C | ~ | C |
| 2 | B | ~ | B |
| 3 | A | ~ | A |
| 4 | 1 | ~ | 14 |
| 5 | 1 | P | NaN |
| 6 | C | ~ | C |
| 7 | D | ~ | D |
| 8 | A | ~ | 7 |
| 9 | B | ~ | B |
| 10 | A | P | NaN |
| 11 | D | ~ | D |
| 12 | B | ~ | 4 |
| 13 | C | ~ | C |
| 14 | B | P | NaN |
| 15 | D | ~ | D |
| 16 | C | ~ | 4 |
| 17 | C | P | NaN |
| 18 | D | ~ | 18 |
| 19 | D | ~ | 9 |
| 20 | D | P | NaN |